# method is undefined for type java arrays

Tags: java

I dont understand why this isnt working, i keep getting an error on the printarray call that says "The method printArray(int[]) is undefined for the type Array_1m"

here is my main class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Array_1m{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] intarray = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5} ;
        System.out.println("Here are our starting arrays");
        printArray(intarray);

        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("");

    }

}
```

here is my array class,  i have to make a bunch of different methods for this class to be used in the main class and im just trying to print two arrays initially in order to manipulate them later.  ill probably be back on here later for more help because I am having so much trouble with this program.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Array_1 {
    int[] internalarray;

    public Array_1(int x) {
        if(x>0) {
            this.internalarray = new int [x];
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error: Array size must be non-negative");

        }

    }
    public static void printArray(int[] intarray) {
           for (int i = 0; i < intarray.length; i++) {
              if (i > 0) {
                 System.out.print(", ");
              }
              System.out.print(intarray[i]);
           }
        }
 }
```

Comment: If you're calling a method from another class, you need to prefix the class name: `Array_1.printArray(intarray);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to import Array_1 in your code file and then you can call printArray as

```
Array_1.printArray(intarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

your program is already work. It is work in my netbeans ide. Please try again to use with some changes in my code. import your Array_1 java class. Her is Array_1m- main method

```
import static stackoverflowtest.Array_1.printArray;

public class Array_1m {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] intarray = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5} ;
        System.out.println("Here are our starting arrays");
        printArray(intarray);

        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

and after this is next java class Array_1

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Array_1 {
    int[] internalarray;

    public Array_1(int x) {
        if(x>0) {
            this.internalarray = new int [x];
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error: Array size must be non-negative");

        }

    }
    public static void printArray(int[] intarray) {
           for (int i = 0; i < intarray.length; i++) {
              if (i > 0) {
                 System.out.print(", ");
              }
              System.out.print(intarray[i]);
           }
        }
 }
```

` this is result [image]

question solve github repositary is https://github.com/randikawann/StackHelpArray_1